# Stokes problem fem

Tags: finite-element-method

I'm looking for a book or pdf to study the Stokes problem with finite elements method

$\Delta u+\nabla p=f$ in $\Omega$

$\nabla\cdot u=0$ in $\Omega$

$+$ boundary conditions (example: $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$.

I'm interested in study the existence and uniqueness of the continuous and discrete problem, in particular the $\mathbb{P}_1/\mathbb{P}_0$ formulation ($\mathbb{P}_1$ for $u$ and $\mathbb{P}_0$ for $p$).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard reference is *Mixed Finite Element Methods and Applications* by Boffi-Brezzi-Fortin. The combination $P_1-P_0$ will not, in general, satisfy the discrete *inf-sup* condition and therefore you must either stabilize the problem or use the so-called nonconforming $P_1-P_0$ approximation where the velocity is continuous only at the triangle edge midpoints (i.e., Crouzeix-Raviart shape functions).

Comment: do you know some stabilized method P1-P0?  I'm looking for just for practice the programming

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know of any $P_1$-$P_0$ stabilized methods for Stokes. The standard (consistent) residual stabilization works for any continuous pressure. For discontinous pressure you need higher-order velocity space (i.e. $P_2$-$P_0$ in two-dimensional problems), see e.g. Stenberg, Videman - On the error analysis of stabilized finite element methods for the Stokes problem. You can find the preprint in arXiv.